# Facebook java script request dialog in android mobile web-app

Tags: android, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I have a facebook mobile web app, that displays an apprequest dialog with preselected friends like this example: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#channels
With iPhone everything works as expected but in Android the request dialog is too wide, see this screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/oiCTlbnbAs

How can I change the width of the request-dialog?
I tried almost everything with the viewport attribute of the HTML document.
Does it have any effect that my HTML document is XHTML traditional?

Answer (score 0):

if you use the Direct URL method, as described in the link below, it will work:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/